# Read first line split based on delimiter and store it in array (in ksh)

Tags: text-processing, ksh

I am reading the first line of the file, header row, split by delimiter `|` and assigning it to array.

```
IFS='|' read -r -a header < "/file_uploads/file_headers.txt"
```

This is working fine in lower environment, but in higher environment it gives error like

```
file_upload_process.sh[47]: read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsSv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n count] [-N count]
            [var?prompt] [var ...]
file_upload_process.sh[48]: read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsSv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n count] [-N count]
            [var?prompt] [var ...]
```

Looks like there is versioning difference in lower and higher environment and causing this issue?
Is there any alternate way to read first line of file in to array with delimiter split?

Comment: What exactly is "lower" and "higher" environment? Also, you have added the `ksh` tag while your title speaks about Bash ...

Comment: @AdminBee lower - development and higher - production environment, or just different servers.

Comment: Please verify the syntax. I think in `ksh` it must be an upper-case `-A` whereas for `bash` it is the lower-case `-a` you show here. Please edit your post with the meaning of "lower" and "higher" environment and indicate the shells used in each.

Comment: The options is `-A` in ksh or zsh (consistent with `set -A`). `-a` if for bash (not related to `set -a`)

Comment: changed to -A and works now. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have different default shells in your "lower" and "higher" environment. The syntax for reading into an array differs between shells:

- for Bash<sup>(1)</sup>, the relevant option is `-a` (lowercase)
- for Ksh, the relevant option is `-A` (uppercase)

It is likely that you "lower" environment, where the syntax works, uses Bash<sup>(1)</sup>, whereas in the "higher" environment Ksh is used. Changing the syntax for the latter to `-A` should solve the problem.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> As noted by Stéphane Chazelas, there is one [variant of `ksh93`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell#History) (which evolved into the now discontinued `ksh2020`) that supported the lower-case `-a` option to provide Bash compatibility. So it might also be that your "lower" and "higher" environments have different variants of Ksh installed.

Comment: It looks like the beta ksh93v- version of ksh93 and on which was based the (now discontinued) ksh2020 added support for `-a` as an alias for `-A` in 2014 for compatibility with `bash`. So that may be the version of ksh the OP has on their "lower" environment. All other versions / clones / variants of ksh, zsh and yash use `read -A`. `bash` chose `-a` instead of `-A` even though it otherwise copied the clunky array design of ksh something like 13 years after it was introduced by ksh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see, thank you. I will add a mention of that in the answer.