# read nth line and split in to array

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to read nth line from file and split in to array based on delimiter

```
HEAD_START=4
IFS='|' read -r -a headers < sed "${HEAD_START}q;d" "/FILE_UPLOADS/Checklist-Relationship (4).txt"
```

The above gives `"sed: cannot open [No such file or directory]"`

But when i run just `sed "${HEAD_START}q;d" "/FILE_UPLOADS/Checklist-Relationship (4).txt"` in the prompt it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read -r -a headers < sed ...` is trying to open a file named `sed` for reading.

In bash, to run `sed` as a command and make its output available on the standard input stream, you can use a *process substitution*:

```
IFS='|' read -r -a headers < <(sed "${HEAD_START}q;d" "/FILE_UPLOADS/Checklist-Relationship (4).txt")
```

Comment: Thanks. Code: `IFS='|' read -r -a headers < <(sed "${HEAD_START}q;d" "/FILE_UPLOADS/Checklist-Relationship (4).txt")` and the error i am getting now is `read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsSv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n count] [-N count] [var?prompt] [var ...]`

Comment: @Pat are you actually using `ksh` rather than `bash`?

Comment: i think yes, i am using ksh

Comment: @Pat in that case, you will need to use `-A` in place of `-a` in the builtin `read` command - see for example [Read first line split based on delimiter and store it in array (in ksh)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677939/read-first-line-split-based-on-delimiter-and-store-it-in-array-in-ksh)

Comment: works and thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the file is not too big, I'd skip sed:

```bash
mapfile -t lines < filename
IFS='|' read -ra headers <<< "${lines[HEAD_START - 1]}"
```